# How can I apply quote to every argument in a function

Tags: r

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
as.character(quote(x))
[1] "x"
```

Now I would like to put it in a function.

```
qq <- function(a) as.character(substitute(a))
qq(x)
[1] "x"
```

Fine. But:

```
qq <- function(...) as.character(substitute(...))
qq(x,y,z)
[1] "x"
```

OK, how about:

```
qq <- function(...) sapply(..., function (x) as.character(substitute(x)))
qq(x,y,z)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
object 'y' of mode 'function' was not found
```

And:

```
qq <- function(...) sapply(list(...), function (x) as.character(substitute(x)))
qq(x,y,z)
Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'z' not found
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
qq <- function(...) sapply(substitute({ ... })[-1], deparse)
qq(a, b, c)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**Note:** `qq <- function(...) as.character(substitute(...))` does work if passed a single argumet: `qq(a)` so the problem is that `substitute` is expecting a single argument, not several.  The `{...}` converts the multiple arguments to one.

Comment: Can you explain why ```substitute({...})``` works while without the curlies, it only returns the first argument?

Answer (score 4):

You could try `match.call`

```
foo <- function(...) {
    sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], deparse)
}
foo(x, y, z)
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
foo(a, b, c, d, e)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

If there are any other arguments, you may want some variation of the above function.

```
foo2 <- function(x, ...) {
    a <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE))$...
    sapply(a, deparse)
}
foo2(5, x, y, z)
# [1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Comment: (+1) for `match.call` Not sure what it does though. Is it just retrieving the values from `...`?

Comment: What's the difference between ```deparse``` and ```as.character(substitute(x))```? Perhaps this is just a general plea for someone to explain ```deparse```, ```substitute```, ```quote```, ```eval```, ```as.expression``` etc. etc....

Comment: Well I'm not going to explain all of them, but `deparse` is generally used to turn unevaluated expressions into character strings, which is what you're doing here.  I also struggled to understand the difference in all of them.  Most of my questions were answered by just trying things out